# quadratic endogenous variables in R

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, quadratic-form, endogeneity

As part of ongoing research I'm to test a certain model on some data. One of the questions asked (c.f. one of the hypotheses) involves estimating the quadratic term of an independent variable (in R). The problem is that there is concern that the variable is endogenous and maybe should be instrumented. Estimating the linear endogenous variable and including its fitted values into my main model (while correcting the standard errors) is not the problem. My question is how I can include the quadratic (instrumented) term of that endogenous variable into my main regression equation?

Assume my main linear model (in R):

**Y ~ X1 + X2,**

where X2 is the endogenous variable and X1 is some exogenous control. Then the model that corrects for the endogeneity of X2 through 2sls method:

**Y ~ X1 + X2hat,**
where **X2hat ~ Z1 + X1,**
and Z1 is some exogenous instrument that influences Y through X2.

I read somewhere that in order to include the quadratic term of the 'instrumented' endogenous variable (X2hat), I would need to estimate the regular quadratic term based on the same regressors (i.e. Z1 + X1) as the linear 'instrumented' endogenous variable.

Main quadratic model (in R):

**Y ~ X1 + poly(X2,2)**,

where poly(X2,2) creates orthogonal linear and quadratic terms of X2 (through QR decomposition). Then the model that adjusts for endogeneity through 2sls would be (assuming what I read is correct):

**Y ~ X1 + X2hat + (X2^2)hat**, 
where **(X2^2)hat ~ Z1 + X1**
Is the method I'm using the correct one? Or should I approach this problem in a different way? Is this even possible or would you expect problems with multicollinearity?

Comment: Is the level **X2** supposed to be a regressor in addition to the squared **X2** (before you go for instrumental variables)? Do you "mean it", or is it an artifact of your instrumental variables approach?

Comment: So, I'm not completely sure if I understand your comment correctly. You're asking whether I'm really interested in seeing whether there is a quadratic term and I'm not just using it as part of my instrumental approach? The answer to that question would be YES. Assuming that I didn't need an instrumental correction in this model, I would also include the linear and quadratic term of X2 (to test my model).

Comment: Since **X2hat** and **(X2^2)hat** are both linear combinations of **Z1** and **X1**, it looks to me that you would have a problem of multicollinearity. **(X2^2)hat** is a linear combination of **X1** and **X2hat**. You should have at least one more instrumental variable (**Z2**) in the system. A side note: **(X2^2)hat** is a non-negative variable; I am not sure if it is a good idea to instrument it using a simple regression. You may get negative fitted values. But maybe it is not a problem, I don't quite know...